# Vagrant Integration in rspec-mode

Tags: ruby-mode, ruby

I have a vagrant machine for my Rails project. I would like to integrate Emacs with rspec, currently done by hand on a terminal (inside the vagrant machine).

If I run `rspec-verify-all` Emacs will try to execute rspec from local shared directory (not from Vagrant obviously) and this does not work, as the Rails environment is not set locally on my computer.

So the question: how to run rspec in Vagrant environment?

Comment: Do you know any other editors that support this? How do they do that?

Comment: See the similar issue about [NixOS environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188054/get-spacemacs-emacs-gui-version-to-recognize-nix-shell-environment)

Comment: https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode/pull/144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the thing to do is to edit the project over TRAMP (not in a shared directory).

Running specs over TRAMP has [just been fixed](https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode/issues/133) in `rspec-mode`.